# How do I lowercase columns names and removing white spaces?

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I need to lowercase the column names and and get rid of the gaps.
After using the method `.lower()` I got an error:

> `'Index' object has no attribute 'lower'`

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `df.columns.str.lower()` Of course, don't forget that this code does not overwrite the existing df.columns.

Comment: Then what should I do to overwrite df columns after this method? and how can I get rid of gaps in the column names?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower casing column names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

Deleting white spaces:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: this one worked, thank you :)

Comment: what about deleting gaps in the column names ? Maybe you can suggest something?

Comment: See updated answer above

Answer (score 2):

To complete previous answers, you can also use map to apply any transformation you want, see the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Column 1": [1, 2, 3],
    "COLUMN 2 ": [4, 5, 6]
})

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.lower().strip())
```

If you want to replace all space by underscore or something like that you can use regex:

```
import re
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: re.sub('\s+', '_', x.lower().strip()))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, `str.lower()` is a direct answer.

You might also be interested in `df.rename(columns=str.lower)` as it returns an entire dataframe with the renamed columns and allows inplace modification.

Comment: thank you so much, what about getting rid of gaps in the column names?

Comment: btw after using the method above I got the column names without any modification

Comment: What do you mean by gaps here -- whitespaces between words? About the 2nd question can you share the screen of the code and output?

Comment: yes, exactly i meant whitespaces. Here's the code 'df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df' as an output i got the same column names with whitespaces (unfortunately i can't share the screen with you in the comments)